# Rails 3 validates_uniqueness_of for two model attributes AND created_at year

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a Projection model which validates the uniqueness of the attribute "ppr". I do not want multiple Projection records where the :week, :player_id, :ppr, AND :created_at year are all the same. **The key problem here is that I do not know how to make this validation specific for the *created_at year***. I don't mind if there are multiple records where :ppr, :player_id, and :week are all the same as long as they are for different created_at years.

For example:

Here is a Projection record.

```
 #<Projection id: 44, ppr: 3.5, salary: 6600, week: 1, created_at: "2014-09-04 06:05:34", player_id: 44>
```

If I want to create this additional Projection record my current validation will not allow it even though the created_at year is 2015 and not 2014.

```
#<Projection id: 89, ppr: 3.5, salary: 6600, week: 1, created_at: "2015-09-05 06:05:34", player_id: 44>
```

How do I modify my validation to account for this additional constraint and allow records from a different year?

I basically need to combine these two validations:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :ppr, :scope => [:week, :player_id], :if => :nfl?

validates_uniqueness_of :ppr, conditions: { -> { where("created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?", "#{Date.today.year}0101", "#{Date.today.year}1231") } }
```

Posted below is how I currently have my model setup:

```
class Projection < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ppr, :salary, :score, :week, :player_id, :created_at

  belongs_to :player

  validates_uniqueness_of :ppr, :scope => [:week, :player_id], :if => :nfl?

  scope :for_year, lambda {|year| where("created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?", "#{year}0101", "#{year}1231")}
end
```

**UPDATE**

This syntax didn't work for obvious reasons but can I do something similar to this?

```
validates_uniqueness_of :ppr, :scope, :created_at => [:week, :player_id, created_at <= ?", "#{Date.today.year}0101", "#{Date.today.year}1231"], :if => :nfl?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend writing a validation method that queries the existence of such a record. Since the data is unique per year, query the date range of the current year.

NOTE: This does assume that all data entry is for the current year since your condition is tied to the created_at attribute. Modify the `range` variable if you need a different time period.

```
class Projection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  delegate :nfl?, to: :player

  validates :player, presence: true
  validate :unique_player_projection, if: :nfl?

  private

  def unique_player_projection
    range = Time.now.beginning_of_year..Time.now.end_of_year
    return unless Projection.exists?(player_id: player_id, ppr: ppr, week: week, created_at: range)
    errors.add(:base, 'Projection not unique.')
  end
end
```

This example is database-agnostic. There is more optimized SQL queries if you are dealing with huge recordsets.

I included a delegate for the `nfl?` attribute.